# Trying to use a double pointer struct to read a csv file and print off the entries but I'm getting "Invalid read of size 8" in C

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

Creating a C program to read a csv file into a double pointer struct but I'm getting a segmentation fault.

This is the struct:

```
typedef struct vehicle{
char *make;
char *model;
char *color;
char *license_plate;
int year;
}vehicle_t;
```

I'm using a single pointer and double pointer in this program to get a better understanding of using pointers:

```
vehicle_t *v = NULL;
vehicle_t **car;
car = calloc(1, sizeof(vehicle_t *));
int num_cars = 0;

while(!fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, fp)){
  //car = calloc(1, sizeof(vehicle_t *));
  *(car+num_cars) = calloc(1, sizeof(vehicle_t));
  *((car)+num_cars) = read_csv(fp, v);
  num_cars++;

  //free(v->year);
  free(v->make);
  free(v->model);
  free(v->color);
  free(v->license_plate);
  free(v);
}
```

Here is the function I created to read csv file and return that in car:

```
vehicle_t *read_csv(FILE *fp, vehicle_t *v){
char buffer[BUF_SIZE] = {0};
    v = calloc(1, sizeof(vehicle_t));
    fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, fp);
        char *tok = strtok(buffer, ",");
        (v)->year = atoi(tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
        (v)->make = calloc(strlen(tok)+1, sizeof(char));
        tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy((v)->make, tok);
        (v)->model = calloc(strlen(tok)+1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy((v)->model, tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
        (v)->color = calloc(strlen(tok)+1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy((v)->color, tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
        (v)->license_plate = calloc(strlen(tok)+1, sizeof(char));
        strcpy((v)->license_plate, tok);

    return v;
   }
```

Valgrind is telling me that I'm getting an issue here when I try to print the vehicles from double pointer car:

```
for(int i= 0; i<=num_cars; i++){
    printf("%d %s %s (%s) LIC:%s\n", ((*car)->year), ((*car)->make), ((*car)-   >model), ((*car)->color), ((*car)->license_plate));
}
```

Valgrind error message:

[image: Valgrind Error Message]

I finish off the code by freeing the car double pointer:

```
for(int i= 0; i<=num_cars; i++){
  //free((*car)->year);
  free((*car)->make);
  free((*car)->model);
  free((*car)->color);
  free((*car)->license_plate);
  free(*car);
  free(car);
}
```

Not sure as to why I'm getting the segmentation fault. Thought I had a decent handle of pointer usage and appeared like allocated and deallocated memory correctly.

Comment: The term "double pointer" is ambiguous. Do you mean a pointer to a `double`, or a pointer to a pointer? Please [edit] your question to clarify and remove such ambiguity. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: On another note, for any pointer or array `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter is usually easier to read, write, and more importantly understand. Also, why are you passing `v` as an argument to the `read_csv` function? That's not needed.

Comment: `while(!fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, fp)){` !!!!!!

Comment: You're only allocated an array large enough for a single point to a vehicle: `car = calloc(1, sizeof(vehicle_t *));`, but then you proceed to try to stuff `num_cars` values into it.

Comment: You also have a memory leak: `cars[num_cars] = calloc(...); cars[num_cars] = read_csv(...);` The pointer returned by the first `calloc` will be lost with the second assignment.

Comment: @wildplasser What's wrong with it?

Comment: @klutt : It attempts to read while there is nothing to read. Which will do nothing if the file is non-empty, and loop forever if the file happens to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

At least these problems:

**Wrong pointer**

```
(v)->make = calloc(strlen(tok)+1, sizeof(char));
tok = strtok(NULL, ",");  // ????
strcpy((v)->make, tok);
```

Code is strange.  Why allocate to a string length and then change `tok` before copying?

I'd expect something more like

```
(v)->make = calloc(strlen(tok)+1, sizeof(char));
strcpy((v)->make, tok);
tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

---

Research `strdup()` for alternative code.

**Only 1 car, wrong `fgets()` usage**

Code only allocates for 1 car

```
//vehicle_t **car;
//car = calloc(1, sizeof(vehicle_t *));
//int num_cars = 0;

//while(!fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, fp)){
//  *(car+num_cars) = calloc(1, sizeof(vehicle_t));
//  *((car)+num_cars) = read_csv(fp, v);

int car_n = 1000;
//                       n cars 
vehicle_t **car = calloc(car_n, sizeof *car);
int num_cars = 0;

//                        v --- no !
while(num_cars < car_n &&  fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, fp)){
  car[num_cars] = calloc(1, sizeof car[num_cars][0]);
  car[num_cars] = read_csv(fp, v);
```